# Can i build some parts of a react native app with java

Tags: java, android, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I am planning to build an app with react native but the problem is that it has a few functions(for eg. monitoring which apps are running in background and pushing notifications if any of the selected apps are being used) which can't be built with react native..So is it possible to build that entire app using react native and these parts using java?

Comment: Try this https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android

Comment: Ohh...thanks a lot! I think that will work!